# Trying to change namecheap select custom dns field using python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver

I got stuck trying to change DNS settings for domains in namecheap using python selenium

Here is the html:

```
<select class="dashed-select add-margin ng-untouched ng-valid select2-offscreen ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ng-change="nameServerChange()" title="" tabindex="-1" data-wrapper="ns" data-nccontrol="visibility" ng-model="selectedNameserver.id" data-ng-class="{'disabled':pageBehavior.overViewModel.IsDomainLocked}" data-ui-select2="NoSearchOption" style="display: block;">
<option value="0">Namecheap BasicDNS</option>
<option ng-hide="domainnameserverViewModel.ProviderName == 'RE'" value="1">Namecheap BackupDNS</option>
<option ng-hide="domainnameserverViewModel.IsHostedServiceAvailable" value="2">Namecheap Web Hosting DNS</option>
<option value="3">Custom DNS</option>
<!-- ngIf: model.PremiumDnsDetails.IsPremiumdDNSBuyed -->
</select>
```

So my question is how do I select the Custom DNS option and then change the fields with my custom nameservers. I know it would be much easier using the API but I would really want a fix using selenium webdriver. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Select` class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) and the `select_by_visible_text()` method:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('select[ng-model="selectedNameserver.id"]'))
select.select_by_visible_text("Custom DNS")
```

Comment: Hi, just tried your answer and I get:  Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"select[ng-model=\"selectedNameserver.id\"]"}

Comment: @RobertWest okay, could you refer me to the page you are working with? Otherwise, this would quickly become a guessing game :)

Comment: Nope, my bad - just tested it and works ok...my bad I forgot to add a wait for element before. Thank you very much for the answer!